# create dynamic table in nHibernate with asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I used entity framework with asp.net mvc3 to create a result publishing site. Since such site requires tables to be generated in a programmatic way at runtime. For example i need to add a table of subjects with marks; And user decides which field to insert & field type too just like phpmyadmin does when creating a new table. So is it possible to do this through nHibernate cauese i heard entity framework lacks in such conditions?? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with the the `Table` and `Driver` class but you have to rebuild the sessionfactory each time you add a new table/entity. SOmething like this:

```
var dialect = Dialect.GetDialect(properties);
var table = new Table();
// add columns

var sql = table.GetSqlCreatestring(dialect);

using (var sf = emptyConfig.BuildSessionfactory())
{
    session.CreateSqlQuery(sql).ExecuteUpdate();
}
```